# Are nested range-based for statements strictly legal?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Consider this code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1 {1,2};
    std::vector<int> v2 {4,5};
    for (auto i : v1) {
       for (auto j : v2) {
          std::cout << i << ',' << j << '\n';
       }
    }
}
```

As expected, [GCC 4.8 compiles it just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95baf92e981f09e3), and the output is:

> 1,4
>   1,5
>   2,4
>   2,5

However, C++11 defines ranged-for thus:

```
{
   auto && __range = range-init;
   for ( auto __begin = begin-expr,
              __end = end-expr;
        __begin != __end;
        ++__begin ) {
     for-range-declaration = *__begin;
     statement
   }
}
```

It *does* say:

> `__range`, `__begin`, and `__end` are variables defined for exposition only

but it doesn't clarify that each ranged-for statement should expand to code in which each of those variables is unique, and therefore does not hide the same variables in an enclosing ranged-for.

To that end, it seems to me that nested ranged-for statements are not guaranteed to work as one would expect.

Are we sure that this is not a defect?

Comment: Are you suggestion that the inner loop may not work because the same expositional variable names may exist?

Comment: Hmm, this sort of feels like asking a non-question and then fishing for points by answering it yourself...

Comment: @Sean: Self-answering is not "fishing for points". It is donating time and energy to help everybody else to learn what I have learned. You are welcome to downvote it if you think it's a non-question, though I would encourage you to first examine the purpose of the [tag:language-lawyer] tag.

Comment: I'm all for people donating time and sharing what they've learned. I'm just amazed that with your reputation score you thought you only just learnt this wasn't an issue in the first place. After all, we had nested `for`, `if` and `while` statements for some time now!

Comment: @Sean: It's about the definition of ranged-`for`, specifically, and the way in which that definition is presented in the standard. It has nothing at all to do with `if` and `while`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes, it's perfectly and strictly legal.**

The whole definition of ranged-for, despite being almost unique in the standard in its being given in terms of code, is not a simple expansion: this structure is designed to be expanded inside a compiler using intermediate representations of all the operations required.

In short, the use of the term "exposition" means this is all effectively pseudo-code anyway.

Besides, if you look closely at the scoping of those variables, there's no way they can conflict with the specified usage same variables declared in an enclosing ranged-for statement, *and* our own `statement` cannot access them anyway. That is, there is no situation in which any hiding of those loop variables could cause unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Isn't that what "exposition only" means? :)

Comment: @jrok not if they expose something different. The key is not the "exposition only" bit, it's the `{}` around the entire construct.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: That would solve any potential "redeclaration" errors (right? I forget how block scopes work in this regard), but it doesn't solve potential name hiding.

Comment: Agree with the secondary note, that even if you did naively expand the loops using the same variables, you would still always get the correct behavior.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I dont think that name hiding is a problem here, the inner for-each block (in which we potential access the variables, so it could also be the second one out of three) will hide the names declared in the more outer ones, correct behaviour IMO.

Comment: @Paranaix: That's a reason that the name hiding _could_ be a problem (in that the name hiding does occur), but my answer agrees that it happens not to be a problem. :)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Actually, since each of those variables is declared outright within this scope, I suppose redeclaration errors are ultimately the worst that could ever conceivably happen. And, yes, the block scope prohibits that.